# Floating Voltage Referenced to Ground

Tags: electricity, reference-frames, electronics

So, I came across something interesting today at work that is completely confusing me. We have floating 130V battery backups, and I am told there is neither any ground reference, nor any center tap on the bank of batteries. As normal, if you measure from positive to negative, you get the full range of 130V, and negative if you flip the leads. If the batteries are not connected to any form of a load, then if you use ground as the reference on your multimeter, you get no voltage(minus a little bit of noise). So far so good.

Here is where I get lost. Put a load across these batteries, and now if you measure with reference to ground, you get +65V on the positive terminal, and -65V on the negative terminal. Without any form of a complete circuit, I for the love of me am not able to understand how a load across a floating battery can produce both a positive and negative voltage! I mean, with a floating system, ground should really be no different than using a sandwich as a reference point. I would assume that any reference point outside the floating system would just produce noise.

If anyone is able to explain this phenomenon to me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Please give details of the load which you used.

Comment: Currently, the load is a little over 5 Amps. There is a floating battery charger in parallel with the batteries and the various electronic equipment. I am told that the equipment doesn't tie any of the DC to ground. I just measured the center point of the batteries to ground, with about 1.8V, which should confirm that it is indeed floating. I also visually saw that there is also no center tap.

Comment: @bob152637485 Based on your comment to Farcher, can I then assume the battery backup is not part of general power system backup (in the event of failure of the power system)? Just want to make sure what the purpose of the battery back  up is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that I'm not familiar with the details on how battery backups are connected to the loads in a building when they are switched onto the loads, so the following might not be correct. But I assume that the backup battery back is an emergency backup and is therefore only connected to the building load when primary power fails and the battery pack is switched onto the load.

Though the battery pack may initially be isolated from ground, once it is connected to the building loads, depending on how it is connected, it may no longer be isolated from ground. That is because the building loads themselves are grounded. In the US the neutral conductors of branch circuits serving loads are tied to ground at the service panel.

Bottom line: Once the load is connected to the battery pack, I suspect your battery pack is no longer isolated from earth ground. So depending exactly on how the pack is connected to the load, you may read a voltage to ground from the battery pack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies, guys, apparently there IS a ground reference, but it is internal to the charger. The 130V had a high resistance voltage divider that is center tapped. Everything makes sense now!